# add .so file armeabi in lib ant build.xml

Tags: android, ant, android-build

I placed a .so file libs/armeabi/my_so.so

**How do I include this file in the ant build.xml file?** I could do that for the jar files in my libs directory. Any code snippet will be appreciated.

Thanks.